# Django Rest Framework Refusing To Accept MultiPart Form Data

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to post data which has nested json, an image and other data. The json looks like this:

```
{
    "id": ,
    "venue": {
        "id": ,
        "name": "",
        "city": "",
        "address": "",
        "rating": null,
        "point": null
    },
    "name": "",
    "time": "",
    "event_pic": null,
    "description": "",
    "event_type": "Movie",
    "invite_only": ,
    "free": ,
    "age_restriction": ,
    "ticket_price": ,
    "user": 
}
```

I am running into a problem where for some reason if I try to use multipart form to upload I get an error message like this:

```
Request http://zacmwa.pythonanywhere.com/api/events/ (7417ms)
    02-14 16:21:26.468 7133-7762/com.wyat.wyat D/OkHttp: Server: openresty/1.9.15.1
    02-14 16:21:26.468 7133-7762/com.wyat.wyat D/OkHttp: Date: Tue, 14 Feb 2017 13:21:26 GMT
    02-14 16:21:26.468 7133-7762/com.wyat.wyat D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json
    02-14 16:21:26.468 7133-7762/com.wyat.wyat D/OkHttp: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    02-14 16:21:26.468 7133-7762/com.wyat.wyat D/OkHttp: Connection: keep-alive
    02-14 16:21:26.468 7133-7762/com.wyat.wyat D/OkHttp: Vary: Accept
    02-14 16:21:26.468 7133-7762/com.wyat.wyat D/OkHttp: X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
    02-14 16:21:26.468 7133-7762/com.wyat.wyat D/OkHttp: Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS
    02-14 16:21:26.468 7133-7762/com.wyat.wyat D/OkHttp: {"venue":["This field is required."]}
    02-14 16:21:26.468 7133-7762/com.wyat.wyat D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (37-byte body)
```

It says {"venue":["This field is required."]} and sends me a 400 Bad Request.

When I sent from Postman I could not send in multipart form but when I used application/json header I was able to solve this.However when using application/json I am unable to send images.

Why isn't it seeing the json object being sent?How does DRF want nested objects to be sent?

In the browsable api form I can create a nested json object and image easily without changing anything. How do I do this for other clients?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR: You can't do that yet.

Longer version:

You can't send images along with JSON out of the box. Multipart doesn't support JSON (cf https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/4881).

The alternative would be to use forms along with the image *but* forms don't support nested data at the moment.

There might be some workaround with base 64 encoded images sent within the JSON but I haven't play with those so I can't say if it's a good option or not.

PS: your issue is because it's sending the data as form encoded. As it doesn't support nested data, it'll complain you field isn't working.

Comment: I can post from the DRF form. Is there a difference?

Comment: as said in my answer, you can use forms but you won't have the nested data which is your issue with validation

Comment: @Linovia is this still the case till now?

Comment: as far as I can tell, yes

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have added `MultiPartParser` in your DRF Parser configuration in your settings file.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser'
        #...
    )
}
```

Also verify that you have specified `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your html form tag

Edit:-
You can't send nested data as multipart content type, and you can't send raw byte data in json. Either use unnested data or encode file data using `base64` or similar.

```
import base64
with open ('sample.txt') as file:
    encoded_content = base64.b64encode(file.read())
```

Don't forget to decode file content in your view.

Comment: I have added those to my settings but the error is still there.

Comment: The only way I can send nested json in postman is using the application/json header. However that header does not support uploading images.